# Flutter Navigation in Search Bar

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I use the MaterialPage route, is create the scaffold inside my search bar.

There's is a way that I can use another widget and not navigator ?

because I can change buildResults and only works with a widget I can't use navigator.push or pushReplacement

```
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // mostrar una vez elegida la opcion    PruebaMapaPage
    return Navigator(onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> MapaPage(
                                  model,
                                  model.selectedCity.lat,
                                  model.selectedCity.lng,
                                ));
        break;

}});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdhMa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add your router in list onTab instead of doing in BuildResults.